# How to choose jobs in scheduled pipleines?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

i am new to creating pipelines and could use some help. I have a gitlab-ci.yml file that i run on every day at a fixed time and inside the main `gitlab-ci.yml` file, i am importing my other ci files which gets run along wih it.

This is what my gitlab-ci.yml file looks like :-

```
before_script:
    - Commands that i am running
stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy
include:
    - '/tests/ci-1.yml'
    - '/tests/ci-2.yml'
```

I have created a new `ci.yml` file which i want to run outside of my main ci and i want to run that twice a day.

```
run-my-tests:
  stage: test
  only:
    - schedules
  script:
    - Script that it will run
```

How can i adjust the ci file so that my new `run-my-tests-ci.yml` file runs twice a day where as other jobs run on a fixed time? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your pipeline always consists of all included YAML files. You can add or remove jobs from the pipeline in certain situations using predefined or custom variables.

In your case, you could set a variable e.g. *TESTS* to true and query this variable in your jobs.

You should also use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rules), as these offer more options.

With the Variable *TESTS* you can run the job "run-my-build" or "run-my-tests" in different scheduled pipelines.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**:

```yaml
    before_script:
        - ...
    stages:
        - build
        - test
        - deploy
    include:
        - '/ci-1.yml'
        - '/ci-2.yml'
```

**ci-1.yml**:

```yaml
    run-my-build:
      stage: build
      rules:
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $TESTS != "true"'
      script:
        - ...
```

**ci-2.yml**:

```yaml
    run-my-tests:
      stage: test
      rules:
        - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $TESTS == "true"'
      script:
        - ...
```

**Schedule Pipeline (UI):**

[image]